# Installing R gsl package with gnu gsl installed at custom location

Tags: r, gsl

I've installed gsl at a custom location (linux system) as I don't have access to the /usr/local directory. When I install the R gsl package, is there a way I can instruct it to search for this directory instead of /usr/local? Help much appreciated.

Comment: You should look into `.libPaths()` .

Comment: `.libPaths()` is already set to my custom folder (which is not the place gnu gsl was installed though). However R gsl still checks `/usr/local` for the version of gsl I've installed. Any idea how I can get it to work? Like what attributes to set when installing the package, or whether gnu gsl has to be installed at a certain location.

I didn't install gnu gsl in the same folder as the one I already specified in `.libPaths()`, for fear that it will mess up with my existing R packages.

Comment: This seems to be a problem concerning "instructing R gsl installation to look for gsl in a particularly directory" rather than specifying a default R library directory. The suggested "answer" does NOT contain a solution to this particular problem. If you agree this is indeed the case, I'd very much appreciate if you could remove the "duplicate" tag. If there is something I missed, please kindly enlighten me and I apologize for the above assertion. Thank you.

Comment: You are right. Your question reads about package options on the second read. Have you seen the installation/compiling instructions in `?Misc`?.